# How to improve and optimize below SQL query?

Tags: sql-server-2008

```
select   
     [dbo].[GetReplacedValue_New](RC.RateCode,0) AS [Rate Type Code]
    ,[dbo].[GetReplacedValue_New](m.Code,0) AS [PMS Code]
    ,[dbo].[GetReplacedValue_New](gm.Code,0) AS [PMS Group Code]        
    ,(CASE  WHEN ct.Name='Association' THEN 'Association'
            WHEN ct.Name='Convention' THEN 'Convention'
            WHEN ct.Name='Corporate' THEN 'Corporate'
            WHEN ct.Name='Government' THEN 'Government'
            WHEN ct.Name='Military' THEN 'Military'
            WHEN ct.Name='Negotiated' THEN 'Negotiated'
            WHEN ct.Name='Package' THEN 'Package'
            WHEN ct.Name='Promotional' THEN 'Promotional'
            WHEN ct.Name='Rack / General' THEN 'Rack'
            WHEN ct.Name='Senior Citizen' THEN 'Senior'
            WHEN ct.Name='Travel Industry' THEN 'Travel Industry'
            WHEN ct.Name='Weekend' THEN 'Weekend'
            ELSE 'Unassigned'
        END) AS [Rate Type Class]           
    ,[dbo].[GetReplacedValue_New](RC.RateCodeName,0) AS [Rate Type Name]
    ,CASE WHEN [dbo].[GetReplacedValue_New](sdesc.Ltext,5) = '' THEN LEFT([dbo].[GetReplacedValue_New](ML.Ltext,5),94) ELSE LEFT([dbo].[GetReplacedValue_New](sdesc.Ltext,5),94) END AS [Short Description]
    ,LEFT([dbo].[GetReplacedValue_New](ML.Ltext,5),2000 ) AS [Long Description]     
    ,(CASE WHEN RC.Active=1 THEN 'Yes' ELSE 'No' END) AS [Active]       
    ,Case When RC.MinLOS > 0 THEN CAST(RC.MinLOS AS VARCHAR) ELSE '' END AS [Min Stay Thru] 
    ,Case When RC.MaxLOS > 0 THEN CAST(RC.MaxLOS AS VARCHAR) ELSE '' END AS [Max Stay Thru] 
    ,CASE WHEN RC.LeadTime > 0 THEN CAST(RC.LeadTime AS VARCHAR) ELSE '' END AS [Min Lead Days]
    ,CASE WHEN RC.BookWithin > 0 THEN CAST(RC.BookWithin AS VARCHAR) ELSE '' END AS [Max Lead Days]         
    ,ISNULL(CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),CASE WHEN RC.BeginSellDate > '2000-01-01' THEN RC.BeginSellDate End, 101),'') AS [Min Sell Date]    
    ,ISNULL(CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),CASE WHEN RC.EndSellDate > '2000-01-01' and RC.EndSellDate < '2070-01-01' THEN RC.EndSellDate END, 101),'') AS [Max Sell Date]      
    ,(CASE WHEN RC.RateCategoryID=22 THEN 'Yes' ELSE 'No' END) AS [Negotiated]      
    ,(CASE WHEN RC.TACommissionable=1 THEN 'Yes' ELSE 'No' END) AS [Commissionable]
    ,CASE WHEN RC.TACommissionable=1 THEN 'COM' ELSE '' END AS [Commission Policy Code]     
    ,(CASE WHEN RC.RestrictedRate=1 THEN 'Yes' ELSE 'No' END ) AS [Restricted]      
    ,(CASE WHEN RC.RateCategoryID=22 THEN 'Yes' ELSE 'No' END) AS [Map as Negotiated Rate on GDS/IDS]
    ,[dbo].[GetReplacedValue_New](rcg.Code,0) AS [Rate Category Code]
    ,[dbo].[GetReplacedValue_New](RCG.Name,0) AS [Rate Category Name]   

    ,isnull(DR.DCODE,'')  AS [Derived From Rate Code]  --*Add using sub-queries 

    ,LEFT([dbo].[GetReplacedValue_New](RC.RateCodeName,1),30) AS [GDS Rate Name]
    ,CASE WHEN [dbo].[GetReplacedValue_New](sdesc.Ltext,5) = '' THEN DBO.DescFormatter([dbo].[GetReplacedValue_New](ML.Ltext,5),0)ELSE DBO.DescFormatter([dbo].[GetReplacedValue_New](sdesc.Ltext,5),0) END AS [GDS Short Description]
    ,DBO.DescFormatter([dbo].[GetReplacedValue_New](ML.Ltext,5),1) AS [GDS  Long Description]       
    ,LEFT([dbo].[GetReplacedValue_New](RC.RateCodeName,3),63) AS [IDS Rate Name]
    ,CASE WHEN [dbo].[GetReplacedValue_New](sdesc.Ltext,5) = '' THEN DBO.DescFormatter([dbo].[GetReplacedValue_New](ML.Ltext,5),2) ELSE DBO.DescFormatter([dbo].[GetReplacedValue_New](sdesc.Ltext,5),2) END AS [IDS Short Description]
    ,DBO.DescFormatter([dbo].[GetReplacedValue_New](ML.Ltext,5),3) AS [IDS Long Description]        
    ,LEFT([dbo].[GetReplacedValue_New](RC.RateCodeName,0),80) AS [BE Rate Name]
    ,CASE WHEN [dbo].[GetReplacedValue_New](sdesc.Ltext,5) = '' THEN LEFT([dbo].[GetReplacedValue_New](ML.Ltext,5),200) ELSE LEFT([dbo].[GetReplacedValue_New](sdesc.Ltext,5),200) END AS [BE Short Description]
    ,LEFT([dbo].[GetReplacedValue_New](ML.Ltext,5),2000) AS [BE Long Description]       
    ,LEFT([dbo].[GetReplacedValue_New](RC.RateCodeName,0),80) AS [Voice Rate Name]
    ,CASE WHEN [dbo].[GetReplacedValue_New](sdesc.Ltext,5) = '' THEN LEFT([dbo].[GetReplacedValue_New](ML.Ltext,5),200) ELSE LEFT([dbo].[GetReplacedValue_New](sdesc.Ltext,5),200) END AS [Voice Short Description]
    ,LEFT([dbo].[GetReplacedValue_New](ML.Ltext,5),2000) AS [Voice Long Description]        
    ,CASE WHEN H.Active=1 THEN 'Yes' ELSE 'No' END AS [Is Hotel Active]

FROM CRS.dbo.Hotel H WITH(NOLOCK)
JOIN CRS.dbo.RateCode RC WITH(NOLOCK) ON RC.HotelID=H.HotelID
LEFT JOIN CRS.dbo.TxtMultiLanguage  ML WITH(NOLOCK) ON ML.HotelID=RC.HotelID AND ML.AuxID=RC.RateCodeID AND ML.LanguageID=H.LanguageID AND ML.TextTypeID=10
LEFT JOIN CRS.dbo.RateCategory ct WITH(NOLOCK) ON rc.RateCategoryID=ct.RateCategoryID       
LEFT JOIN CRS.dbo.PmsMapping m WITH(NOLOCK) ON m.EntityType=101 AND m.EntityID=RC.RatecodeID AND m.HotelID=RC.HotelID
LEFT JOIN CRS.dbo.RatecodeGroup rcg WITH(NOLOCK) ON RC.RateCodeGroupID=rcg.RateCodeGroupID AND rcg.HotelID=RC.HotelID AND rcg.Active=1
LEFT JOIN CRS.dbo.PmsMapping gm WITH(NOLOCK) ON gm.EntityType=112 AND m.EntityID=rcg.RatecodeGroupID AND m.HotelID=rcg.HotelID
LEFT JOIN CRS.dbo.TxtMultiChannel sdesc WITH(NOLOCK) ON sdesc.EntityType=101 AND sdesc.EntityID=RC.RateCodeID AND sdesc.TextTypeID=10 AND sdesc.ChannelID=1
LEFT JOIN (
        SELECT A.HotelID,A.RateCodeID,A.RateCode,A.MasterID,B.Name AS DCODE FROM 
        CRS.dbo.Hotel H WITH(NOLOCK) JOIN 
        (
        SELECT l.MasterID ,o.RateCodeID,o.RateCode,O.HotelID
        FROM CRS.dbo.Ratecode o WITH(NOLOCK) JOIN CRS.dbo.RateLinkage l WITH(NOLOCK) ON l.RateLinkageID=o.RateLinkageID AND O.HotelID=L.HotelID AND L.EntityType=101 
        where o.Active=1 
        )A  ON H.HotelID=A.HotelID
        JOIN 
        (SELECT HotelID, RatecodeID AS ID,Ratecode AS Name,ChainRatecodeID AS ChainItemID 
        FROM CRS.dbo.Ratecode WITH(NOLOCK)
        WHERE Active=1 
        AND RateLinkageID=0
        )B ON A.HotelID=B.HotelID  AND NOT B.ID=A.RateCodeID AND H.HotelID=B.HotelID
        WHERE  h.HotelID > 0 AND h.ChainID NOT IN (32,103)
)DR on h.HotelID=DR.HotelID AND RC.RateCodeID=dr.RateCodeID
WHERE rc.ChainRateCodeID = 0  AND h.HotelID > 0 AND h.ChainID NOT IN (32,103) and rc.Active=1
```

Comment: Please add schema of tables involved,count and execution plan of the query

Comment: Remove all the scalar functions.  Ensure data is cleaned on entry into the respective tables, rather than in the presentation layer.  That will undoubtedly transform performance of this query.

Comment: Functions...functions everywhere...

Comment: As in 'Get rid of them'.....don't add more....

Comment: Hi there, welcome to the site. When asking to improve a query it helps to see an execution plan and table definitions. Then again i agree with Mark and Bob, the functions are probably killing you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rewrite your scalar functions so that they are inline table-valued functions. Using scalar functions like that will mean that they execute once for EVERY ROW. Switching to an inline table-valued function and then CROSS APPLYing that function to your query will mean the function is only run once. You should see significant performance improvement with this approach. Outside of that, examine the execution plan, check for missing indexes, expensive key lookups and high cost scans.